# How to Integrate Exponential Moving Average into a Strategy on Pine Editor in Trading View

Tags: pine-script

I would like to know if it is possible to integrate into my strategy, an exponential moving average, starting from the indicator:

But that the timeframe is modifiable in my strategy. I hope to express well so that you understand.

Thank you in advance

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Exponential", shorttitle="EMA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ta.ema(src, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

typeMA = input.string(title = "Method", defval = "SMA", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="Smoothing")
smoothingLength = input.int(title = "Length", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing")

smoothingLine = ma(out, smoothingLength, typeMA)
plot(smoothingLine, title="Smoothing Line", color=#f37f20, offset=offset, display=display.none)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and it will work on the timeframe you choose.
Just copy the Moving Average code in your strategy.
Do not copy this 2 first line :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Exponential", shorttitle="EMA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
```

and check that do not use the same name variables twice.